# MySQL server query bloom filter

Tags: mysql, sql, bloom-filter

I'm looking for some feature or system that allows me to predict whether or not a database query will give different results.

Scenario:

```
client 1: SELECT * FROM table_x WHERE age >= 18    # at 12:30:00
```

Then another client updates the database:

```
client 2: INSERT INTO table_x (age) VALUES (20)   # at 12:31:00
```

I want something that will respond TRUE to this question, without talking to the database backend:

```
client 1: didChange('SELECT * FROM table WHERE age >= 18', '12:30:00')
```

This obviously seems to be quite complex technology. Does anybody know if this exists?

Obviously, this system would have to monitor all the update and insert queries, and keep an in-memory structure that can quickly respond TRUE or FALSE to the didChange()-function..

Comment: I don't *think* that it's possible to know what's in your database without querying the database ... you could have your application run its own SQL profiler and then have the application keep track of changes to the database itself at runtime, but that seems like a fairly extensive idea.

Comment: @Sippy It seems like an extensive idea, yes. My intention here is to be able to support the "if-modified-since" header from mobile clients, without querying the database.

Comment: The only way I can think to do it sanely is to set a flag on a `changetracking` table and query that instead, as it wouldn't incur a large overhead.